# MemoryError does not cause program to quit

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, memory

I have a Python3.4 (64-bit) program that is meant to load a lot of data (it takes about 15 Gb of disk space, but I discard half the columns) into a simple dict. The code is as follows:

```
print('Reading accessions', file=sys.stderr)
taxids = {}
taxfile = open('prot.accession2taxid')
taxfile.readline()
for line in taxfile:
    l = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    taxids[l[0]]=int(l[2])
with open('/dev/shm/taxids.pickle', mode='w') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(taxids, '/dev/shm/taxids.pickle')
    print('Dumped', file=sys.stderr)
```

The file is, basically, a TSV:

```
[amorozov@node006 nr]$ head -n 3 prot.accession2taxid 
accession       accession.version       taxid   gi
APZ74649        APZ74649.1      36984   1137646701
AQT41667        AQT41667.1      1686310 1150388099
```

When the memory consumption, as measured by `htop`, reaches about 40 Gb (out of 64 Gb available), the following exception is printed to the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../scripts/rename_sequences.py", line 66, in <module>
    taxids[l[0]]=int(l[2])
MemoryError
```

However, the script does not crash, and it even continues doing *something*. The single core it was running on is still 100% loaded, but no further output is generated, nor does the program continue, as file in /dev/shm/ is not generated. I understand that from a practical point of view the answer is "use SQL" (although I kinda hoped I'd manage to fit ~8 gig of plaintext into 64 gig of memory; maybe it leaks somewhere?), but what is even happening? The exception doesn't seem to get caught, but it doesn't crash the script either.

Comment: Are you sure the core is not assigned to another task (that now takes 100%)?

Comment: Yes. It shows CPU/memory consumption per task and that's the one.

Comment: There is a bigger design issue here: why do you need to read the entire file into memory in the first place? The pickle file seems to be standing in for a proper database, which could be built incrementally instead of building its image in memory as a dict.

Comment: For a speed of data retrieval. I'd need a random access to (all or almost all of) this data later, so storing it all in memory seemed a quicker solution than something-SQL. Of course I understand that SQL solution would be more obvious, but it will also be slower and there is a lot of available memory. Not a big enough lot, but still. The pickle is solely to save some time on parsing during the further runs of the same script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hypothesis proposed by [Rhomboid at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/62kopx/a_weird_thing_with_memoryerror/dfnatt2/): the script actually does terminate, but termination takes a lot of time because GC takes some time to collect bazillion of objects in the dict. At the very least, it is supported by the fact that if I leave the process running, it does finish in several minutes.